# FLASH - Loading Sound from Different Host/Domain

Tags: flash, audio, remote-access, embedding

I have made an Audio Player in Flash that is embedded in JSP. which sets Param when JSP is loaded which Plays mp3 file that is availabe on my server, i.e. I passes path like

**/dirOnMyServer/sample.mp3**

But when I place Path of a file placed on any Other Server like

**http://www.SomeOtherHost.com/url/sample.mp3**

then my SWF does not plays(Stream) that file, But if i individually just opens SWF & puts same Other Host's Path then also it Plays the file

In Simple Words,
Whenever a Remote File(On someother Server) is not played on SWF object if it is on HTML(JSP) but same File works & Streamed successfully if it is Played on same SWF without Embedding it in HTML(JSP)

I have used the Code:

```
cool=new Sound(Audio);
cool.loadSound("http://www.SomeOtherHost.com/url/sample.mp3",true);
```

(EDIT)

Here

> www.SomeOtherHost.com

is not my server, Actually in my application User will put path of anuy mp3 that will be processed on my Page, So

Let http://www.SomeOtherHost.com/url/sample.mp3 be the Path that is being entered by User

(it is Preassumed that User will enters only path having mp3 File)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put [crossdomain.xml](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28844/crossdomain-file-loading/) file on your http://www.SomeOtherHost.com with permission to your first domain to open files.

Comment: Sorry Cherniv may be my explanation is not correct but here, http://www.SomeOtherHost.com is not my server it is of some other Party then in that case what should i do?? Should i put Crossdomain.xml in My Server or at server from which i want to access file.

Comment: You must place it on someotherhost.com , have a look here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html , (you can find the words "different domain" on this page to jump to related part)

Comment: Oh thanks I got your Point, So I will not be able to do this. But Thanks Alot Cherniv for Spending Time for my Question